# How can I make vscode auto indent when I create empty html tag in a vue file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I config my vscode with `editor.autoIndent=full`, and it makes me can do that like this:

```html
<div></div>
```

==> prese enter between `><`

```html
<div>
  (← here will have an auto indent)
</div>
```

But, when I do this in a vue template file, it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix? thx!

check it works fine with html file, but doesn't work with vue template.

Comment: what language mode is active? Check the indicator at the bottom right of the screen.

Comment: You can use the extension Volar (or Vetur, as former version) with ESLint